# data from sql server to bigquery

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I am farely new to bigquery so this might be an easy one to answer.
I need data from my local data warehouse to be transferred to bigquery and to be updated on a daily basis.
How can I do this? I tried reading some guides from google but it isn't working.
How much will it cost? When I convert the data into a csv, the size is around 300 MB.

Thanks!

Comment: you can quick start from airbyte to define source from mssql and destination is your bigquery project https://docs.airbyte.com/quickstart/deploy-airbyte